# Intersection of a cube and a line in $R^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-analysis

Assuming in $R^n$ we have a line and a cube with nonempty intesection. Is the itersection a line? This true for $n=1,2,3$. But, is this true for any $n$?  Can anybody recommend me a good  reference book about this topic? Thank you so much!

Comment: A cube is bounded and the line is unbounded...By Cube you mean surface or also the inner part?

Comment: It's an interval. Note that the $n$-cube is a convex set.

Comment: It may also be a singleton which I would not call a line.

Comment: Why do you need a "reference book" for this trivial question? Of course, the intersection is never a line; it may be a single point, or a closed interval (line segment) on the line. The proof is like this: the cube is compact and convex. This means the intersection, as a subset of the line, must be closed and connected. So it is a point or a closed line segment. No book needed.

Comment: Sorry for the silly question. But I need some books since I am not familiar with this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: a cube $Q$ is always a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n:$ you can convince about this considering coordinates $x_1,\dots,x_n$ such that $Q=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n|a_1\leq x_1\leq a_1+l, \dots, a_n\leq x_n\leq a_n+l\}$ where $l$ is the size of the edge and $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n.$

Thanks to convexity it is easy to deduce that the intersection is a segment, which can be intended also in its degenerate case, that is a single point.

Ps: be careful then, because the intersection is not a *line*, which has infinite length, but a segment, that is a portion of a line.

Comment: Or a degenerate segment (a single point). Perhaps "segment" includes this special case, but it doesn't hurt to mention it explicitly.

Comment: You're totally right.

Comment: Tnx. Can you recommend some books on this topic?

Comment: TBH, no. I mean, the best Linear Algebra book that I know is Serge Lang's "Linear Algebra", but I don't really know if it touches also this specific kind of arguments.